# Should we use carpet tape or tack strips?

Tags: installation, carpet

We want to install commercial carpet in a basement that currently has damaged linoleum/vinyl tiles over concrete. Can we use carpet tape around the parameter or do we need to install tack strips? We plan to install padding underneath the carpet.

Comment: Are there ABSOLUTELY NO Moisture issues in this basement? If the current damage is water damage, adding carpet without first TOTALLY SOLVING any moisture issue is just making a mold and mildew factory.

Comment: Neither, don't put carpet in rentals.

Comment: There is no moisture in the basement, and this carpet is a commercial-grade roll that we already own and want to use up (not something we would otherwise use). When it becomes damaged we will replace it with something else.  We have since decided that using carpet strips is the way to go since we will be putting a pad underneath, which might cause slippage to the carpet if using tape only.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's long abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the linoleum, clean out any mold.... and use tape instead of tack strips and padding. Save yourself some money since it’s a basement.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get rid of the linoleum for sure.  When I installed carpet as a helper to a professional, we always used tack strip.  They sell it with concrete nails, but it takes a strong hammer blow to get each nail in.  If you don't hit it hard enough, some concrete will just chip.  Be prepared for tennis elbow.

Comment: When I have installed carpet ,there has been too much tension for tape , tack strips were required. Of course you could just lay carpet on the floor and use tape at edges like door ways ; this work well when the carpet has some weight.